# Set annotation for same coordinate points matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, annotations, label

I have 12 different points and 10 of them are related to the first two; I want to set label for each of this 10 points individually, but sometimes two or more of them have the same coordinate yet I want to show all the label for that coordinate (not on top of each other but readable)
As you can see in the below picture two set of points have the same coordinate and the label of them have overlapping

```
booleanFunction = np.array(["K","I","H" ,"G", "F", "E" , "D" , "M", "B", "A"])
pointsx = np.empty((rs.shape[1],1))
pointsy = np.empty((rs.shape[1],1))
....
....
....
pl.figure()
pl.hold(True)
pl.plot(X1, Y1, 'ro', X2, Y2, 'y<')
pl.plot(pointsx, pointsy, 'b3')

for i in range (len(pointsx)):
    pl.annotate(booleanFunction[i], xy=(pointsx[i], pointsy[i]), xycoords='data', textcoords='data')
```

[image: dd]

Answer (score 4):

I one of my codes to avoid annotation overlap I do something like this:

```
xoffset = 0.1
switch = -1
for i in range (len(pointsx)):
    pl.annotate(booleanFunction[i], xy=(pointsx[i], pointsy[i]), 
                xytext=(pointsx[i]+switch*xoffset, pointsy[i]),
                xycoords='data', textcoords='data')

    switch*=-1
```

This writes your annotated text alternatively shifted left and right `xoffset` from the point you want to annotate. Of course you can use something similar for the y direction or for both.

Comment: it just shifted the label from the point my problem is that two label overlap each other (cause it belong to two different points which have the same coordinate)

Comment: If two overlapping points are, for example, in index 2 and 4 of the points lists, then the labels will still overlap. You have few possibilities here: 1. If the points are not many, offsetting in x **and** direction might be enough; 2) sort the point and labels and use the offset; 3) in the loop check if the new point overlap any of the points already annotated and shift the annotation using `xytext`